# What are the defining moments that make community realise the potential of deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, history

Consider the [following paragraph](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf#page=50) from the chapter named **pre-trained models** from the textbook titled [Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf) by *Eli Stevens et al*.

> The AlexNet architecture won the 2012 ILSVRC by a large margin, with a
> top-5 test error rate (that is, the correct label must be in the top 5
> predictions) of 15.4%. By comparison, the second-best submission,
> which wasn’t based on a deep network, trailed at 26.2%. **This was a
> defining moment in the history of computer vision: the moment when the
> community started to realize the potential of deep learning for vision
> tasks**. That leap was followed by constant improvement, with more
> modern architectures and training methods getting top-5 error rates as
> low as 3%.

This paragraph is mentioning a moment that makes the community realize the potential of deep learning. Are there any other similar defining moments in the history of deep learning?